# Higher-order function to do throttling, written two ways

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, comparative-review, meta-programming

I have used below method for throttling which is a Higher Order Function (HOF), but find some difficulties to choose which one is better way to write it. Below are both methods.

1. return of the `setTimeout()` assigned in a variable

```
const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
  let timerId;
  if (timerId) {
    return;
  }
  return (...args) => {
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      return fn(...args);
    }, delay);
  };
};
```

2. used a boolean variable (used in snippet)

```
const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
  let inThrottle = false;
  return (...args) => {
    if (inThrottle) return;
    inThrottle = true;
    fn(...args);
    setTimeout(() => (inThrottle = false), delay);
  };
};
```

```js
const positionElement = document.querySelector('#positionElement');
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
/*

const throttle2 = (fn, delay) => {
  let timerId;
  if (timerId) {
    return;
  }
  return (...args) => {
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      return fn(...args);
    }, delay);
  };
}; 

*/

const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
  let inThrottle = false;
  return (...args) => {
    if (inThrottle) return;
    inThrottle = true;
    fn(...args);
    setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, delay);
  }
};

const logMousePosition = (e) => {
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = e;
  positionElement.innerHTML = `
            X: ${clientX}
            Y: ${clientY}
            Time: ${new Date().toUTCString()}
            `;
};


main.addEventListener('mousemove', throttle(logMousePosition, 5000));
```

```css
main {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 2em;
  transform: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  will-change: content;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">Main</main>

<section id="positionElement"></section>
```

Which is the better way to write it?